# Use output of one function and average it in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

please keep in mind that while I showcase my code, that I am fairly new to programming. So please forgive any problems. I am writing a piece of python code that uses the output of one function and then averages it in another function. I am having troubling proceeding on how to do that, this is what I have so far:

```
def avg(A):
    if not A:
        return 0
    return sum(A) / len(A)
```

Using the function above, I have to use it to calculate the average of the function produced below:

```
def SampleFunction(): # Example Function
    A = list(range(300))
    for i in range(300):
        if i%2:
            A[i] = 3.1*(i+1)**1.2 - 7.9*i
        else:
            A[i] = 4.2*(i+2)**.8 - 6.8*i
    return A
```

Below this is a function I have trying to tie the two together.

```
def average(SampleFunction):
    if len(SampleFunction) == 0: return 0
    return sum(SampleFunction) / len(SampleFunction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def avg(A):
    if not A:
        return 0
    return sum(A) / len(A)

def SampleFunction(): # Example Function
    A = list(range(300))
    for i in range(300):
        if i%2:
            A[i] = 3.1*(i+1)**1.2 - 7.9*i
        else:
            A[i] = 4.2*(i+2)**.8 - 6.8*i
    return avg(A)     #Return the avg of A instead of just A
```

Comment: You're answers makes a lot of sense also! Can't believe I miss things that are simple like this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right at the moment of passing `SampleFunction` as parameter, but it's a **function**, you have to call invoke it inside `average()`:

```
def average(some_function):
    result = some_function() # invoke
    return avg(result) # use the already defined function 'avg'
```

When you call it, pass the function you want to `average()`:

```
print average(SampleFunction)
```

**Note:**

- I would recommend you to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Names like `SomeName` are used for classes, whereas names like `some_name` are used for functions.

Comment: I can't believe something so simple has passed my mind! Comes to show you that you should take breaks during coding. A wonderful and easy to understand answer!